# In MS Flow, how do I loop through an array and extract values from array?

Tags: power-automate

I have http rest result in this format:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "page": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "total": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        },
        "list": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "id",
                    "type",
                    "status"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to loop through each item in "list" and extract the id, type, status.  How do I do this in MS Flow?  Here is what I got:

[image: MyFlow]

As you can see the variables are not in the dynamic content picker, how do I get it to show up?

Comment: in your *Apply to each* choose **Current item** as the field for the loop, then the *Parse JSON* value shuld be available